# Python package error even after installing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, package

I'm using python on vs code.
I created a virtual environment. Activated it. Installed packages with pip but still in code it says no module name found error.

Comment: check your VS interpreter. is it pointing to the env ?

Comment: Did one of the answers help? Then please accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "activated it" you mean you have called its `activate` script within the shell? Then only the shell knows about your environment, you still need to tell VS Code where it is.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette, run command `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)` and add the following line to set the Python interpreter of the workspace to the one in your virtual environment:

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "path/to/your/venv/bin/python"
```